# Javascript - sort an array of multiple objects of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

I tried with no success to sort an array of multiple objects of objects.

Here my database :

```js
var jsonDatas = [
    {
        "type": "Voiture",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Fiat Punto",
                "description": "Je suis une voiture",
                "price": 10000,
                "quantity": 2,
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Porsche 911",
                "description": "Je suis une belle voiture",
                "price": 80000,
                "quantity": 0,
            }, 
        ],
    },
    {
        "type": "Maison",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Villa sur la plage",
                "description": "Quelle belle vue",
                "price": 870000,
                "quantity": 1,
            }, {
                "name": "Maison à la campagne",
                "description": "Vive le calme",
                "price": 170000,
                "quantity": 3,
            }
        ],
    }
```

I want my datas are ordered by items name (alphabetical order) : obtain Fiat, Maison, Porsche, Villa, problem is the type, because it sort first the type then the products

[image]

I tried this for example :

```js
function sortDatasASC(){
  database.forEach(element =>
     element.items.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1)),
  catalogFiltered();
```

I tried to create an intermediate array to push items and then reassociate with the type but it doesn't work.

For example, this work for a checkbox who display products if there are on stock, but can't duplicate it for a sorting

```js
const choiceStock = document.getElementById('stockCheck').addEventListener('change', function () {

  let datas = [];

  if (this.checked) {

    let filter = [];
    database.forEach(element =>
      filter.push({ 'type': element.type, 'items': element.items.filter(test => test.quantity > 0) })
    );
    datas = filter;

  } else {
    datas = database;
  }
  showCatalog(datas);
});
```

If you have any ideas!?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I want my datas are ordered by items name (alphabetical order) : obtain Fiat, Maison, Porsche, Villa

Comment: Please edit the Q and provide expected output

Comment: `problem is the type, because each time, it sort first the type then the products by type` how can this be a problem?

Comment: I add a picture to explain it, my datas are ordered first by type (voiture, maison) then by name and i need a sorting just by name of the product no matter the type

Comment: @Stoule_dev: you don't publish all data. For instance: where is the Peugeot 205 in the data?

I assume there are multiple objects of `"type": "Voiture"` in your `jsonDatas` array.

If you need to order regardless of the type (either "Voiture" or "Maison" or other), I would suggest you to make your `jsonData` an array of objects where the `item` array only contains a single object. Once made that transformation, you can sort the whole `jsonData` by the name of the single object at [0] in the `items` array.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is grouped by types but since you want it sorted by name instead of by type/name, I would flatten the structure into an array of objects and then apply the logic as you have above:

```
const flattened = jsonDatas.reduce((acc, entry) => {
  //since we dont want to lose the type information I'm cloning
  //each item and adding a type property to it.
  const items = entry.items.map(i => ({ ...i, type: entry.type }));
  return acc.concat(items);
}, []);

flattened.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.name.toLowerCase() === b.name.toLowerCase()) {
    return 0;
  }
  return a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
});

//the type is retained so we can rebuild the structure:
const restructured = flattened.map(item => ({
  type: item.type,
  items: [item],
}));

console.log(flattened);
console.log(restructured);
```

I'm also making the assumption that you want a case insensitive sort. If that's not the case, go ahead and remove the "toLowerCase" calls.

Comment: Thanks. This method is ok to sort products by name but the structure of const sorted is different of initial database, I lost the type and the display doesn't work.

Comment: @Stoule_dev I didn't write the code, but "type" is there under the property `group`, and what do you mean with "display doesn't work"?

Comment: @Stoule_dev I modified my answer to put everything back into a structure like you expect. I would suggest modifying your display code handle a flat list but if you have good reason not to, see the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a flat array. To be able to sort by `type` property, you need to add the `type` to each element.
You can also change the sorting function depending on the property  type (strng / number).
This is just a simple example: :

```js
const jsonDatas=[{type:"Voiture",items:[{name:"Fiat Punto",description:"Je suis une voiture",price:1e4,quantity:2},{name:"Porsche 911",description:"Je suis une belle voiture",price:8e4,quantity:0}]},{type:"Maison",items:[{name:"Villa sur la plage",description:"Quelle belle vue",price:87e4,quantity:1},{name:"Maison à la campagne",description:"Vive le calme",price:17e4,quantity:3}]}];

const flatData = jsonDatas.flatMap(({ items, type }) => items.map(item => ({ ...item, type })));

const sortBy = (arr, property, direction = 'asc') => {
  if (arr.length === 0) return [];
  const propertyType = typeof arr.at(0)[property];
  
  const sortCallbacks = {
    string: (e1, e2) => e1[property].localeCompare(e2[property]),
    number: (e1, e2) => e1[property] - e2[property],
  };
  
 const sortedAsc = arr.sort(sortCallbacks[propertyType]);
 if (direction === 'asc' ) return sortedAsc;
 return sortedAsc.reverse();
};

console.log(sortBy(flatData, 'name' ));
console.log(sortBy(flatData, 'type', 'dsc'));
console.log(sortBy(flatData, 'price', 'dsc'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution, see below if this can helps some of you :

```js
function createArrayToSort(database) {
  let datas = [];
    database.forEach(element =>
      element.items.forEach(items =>
          datas.push({'type': element.type, 'items': [items]})  
    ))
    return datas;
};

 function sortByName(direction){
  let datas = createArrayToSort(database);
    if(direction == "ASC") {
        datas.sort((a, b) => (a.items[0].name > b.items[0].name) ? 1 : -1);
    } else {
        datas.sort((a, b) => (b.items[0].name > a.items[0].name) ? 1 : -1);
 }
  showCatalog(datas);
};

function sortByPrice(direction){
  let datas = createArrayToSort(database);
    if(direction == "ASC") {
        datas.sort((a, b) => (a.items[0].price > b.items[0].price) ? 1 : -1);
    } else {
        datas.sort((a, b) => (b.items[0].price > a.items[0].price) ? 1 : -1);
 }
  showCatalog(datas);
};
const nameASC = document.getElementById('nameASC').addEventListener('click', function () {
sortByName('ASC')
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The snippet you published cannot be run. Try to post something that can be tested.

Comment: You do not explain the solution to your own problem. You had to split your `jsonDatas` into objects with just one item in the `items` array. That is the key, and your sample data in the question does not indicate that there can be multiple objects of "type": "Voitures". IMHO that is key to understand both the problema and the solution.

Comment: Also, you add code to sort by price, which is not part of the original question. Edit your question if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The `jsonDatas` definition your shown in the snippet of your question does not match the screenshot, where other values are shown (e.g.  *Peugeot 205* as a `"type": "Voiture"` entry). The presence of that *Peugeot 205* value denotes that the complete `jsonDatas` array contains other objects of the same type (`Voiture` or `Maison`) apart from the objects you listed.

If that is the way the `jsonDatas` is structured then, to have it sorted as you want, you would need to do two things:

1. First: convert `jsonDatas` into an array of objects such as those objects contains an `items` array with just one element. That will let you manage the order of the records individually. In my snippet below that would be the result in the `singleItem` array.
2. Second: after you have transformed your input into `singleItem` style array, then you can simply sort that array by the name of the unique item in the `items` array (that is: `.items[0].name`).

Below you can see the working code. I used [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as these are convenient methods to do the transformation of step #1.

```js
var jsonDatas = [
    {
        "type": "Voiture",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Fiat Punto",
                "description": "Je suis une voiture",
                "price": 10000,
                "quantity": 2,
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Porsche 911",
                "description": "Je suis une belle voiture",
                "price": 80000,
                "quantity": 0,
            }, 
        ],
    },
    {
        "type": "Maison",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Villa sur la plage",
                "description": "Quelle belle vue",
                "price": 870000,
                "quantity": 1,
            }, {
                "name": "Maison à la campagne",
                "description": "Vive le calme",
                "price": 170000,
                "quantity": 3,
            }
        ],
    }
]

var singleItem = jsonDatas.flatMap(t => t.items.map(i => { return { type: t.type, items: [ i ] } }))
var sorted = singleItem.sort((a, b) => a.items[0].name.localeCompare(b.items[0].name))
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score -3):

For simple sorting via type is just like be

`jsonDatas.sort((a, b) => (a.type > b.type) ? 1 : -1)`